# Expression.Error: The key didn't match any rows in the table

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am trying to fix an Access/Excel tool that my co-worker created, and I'm not sure how to do it. She just left the company, so I am unable to reach out to her for questions about this tool.

She's got a button set up in an Excel sheet. When pressed, the button is supposed to create a new sheet and pull in a QueryTable from an Access database.

Here is her code:

```
Sub Import()
'
' Import Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+I
'

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=1stEmail-MailMergeReady;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [1stEmail-MailMergeReady]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

When the button is pressed, it successfully creates the new sheet, and then freezes on creating the table (`ExternalData_1: Getting Data ...`).  I receive this error message:

```
Expression.Error: The key didn't match any rows in the table
```

When I click Debug, it highlights the `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` line.

I tried replacing that line with simply `.Refresh` and received the same error message. I have also confirmed that all locations it's pointing to are valid and haven't moved at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like the values (possibly emails) in your spreadsheet don't exist in your table `1stEmail-MailMergeReady`

Comment: @Zaider I tried to look a little deeper to see if there are any values that the code is calling that aren't in the Access table, but I can't find anything... it doesn't look like the code is calling any specific columns/values at all - it should just be copying and pasting everything in that specific table into the Excel spreadsheet, regardless of the columns/values. I'm not sure what I'm missing - do you have any idea?